# Finding time constant in terms of R and C

Tags: capacitor, resistors, time-constant

I got a different expression for the time constant than the actual solution. Can anybody tell me where I went wrong? Why is it that in the solution all three resistors were put in parallel? What do you think is the correct way to go about doing this?[image]

Comment: Look at \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$. They are obviously in parallel. Convert them to their parallel equivalent and replace them with the new resistor value. Now, you have a resistor divider formed by this new resistor and \$R_1\$. Convert this to its Thevenin source+resistance equivalent. To do that, you must treat \$R_1\$ as being in parallel with the newly created resistor (not by adding it) which itself was \$R_2\$ in parallel with \$R_3\$. That's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is effectively an AC analysis with time constants, you short out the Voltage source since it is 0 Ohms then you can see R1//R2//R3=Req gives you the correct resul for \$\tau=Req*C\$

While a DC voltage divider gives you the steady state voltage for Vc.

Comment: Thanks! It seems I did not go all the way through with this problem by turning off all the independent sources.

Answer (score 2):

The following steps are the transformations that are probably easiest to see, in order:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNeN8S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You did the first step, correctly. That was just two resistors obviously in parallel with each other. That's Step 1 shown above.

However, for the following step you don't add \$R_1\$. The reason is that once you've reached the upper-right corner schematic, you are left with a voltage divider pair of resistors. And this means you need to perform a "source transformation."

To help make the transformation a little clearer to discuss, I decided to ground the (+) rail. The reason is that \$R_1\$ is in parallel with \$C_1\$ and grounding the top rail allows me to flip the schematic over (upside down, from the voltage perspective) to make the resistor divider analysis a little more obvious. That's Step 2, above.

A Thevenin source transformation of a voltage source and a resistor divider pair is pretty simple. In your case, the new equivalent voltage source is \$V_\text{TH}=V_\text{source}\cdot\frac{R_1}{R_1+\left(R_2\mid\mid R_3\right)}\$, where \$V_\text{source}=-V_1\$, and its source impedance is \$R_\text{TH}=\frac{R_1\cdot\left(R_2\mid\mid R_3\right)}{R_1+\left(R_2\mid\mid R_3\right)}\$; this latter calculation simply being \$R_1\$ in parallel with \$R_2\mid\mid R_3\$.

If you haven't been exposed to the Thevenin source transformation for a voltage source and a resistor divider pair, as yet, then you should immediately work on that problem and make sure you understand why it works as it does.

Comment: Thank you! I messed up on finding R Thevenin because I did not turn off the voltage source.